# 記号などが含まれた文字列と単語の一致検索プログラムについて

Tags: python, python3, 自然言語処理, 文字コード

#### 実現したいこと

記号などが含まれた文字列が与えられて、配列の単語が含まれている場合、その単語を返すというプログラムを書いています。

具体的には以下のようなことがしたいです。

```
text = "orange/apple:grape-peach T-shirt [fruites]"
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'peach', 'T-shirt', 'fruites', 'T', 'shirt']

#求めたい出力
#'apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'peach', 'T-shirt', 'fruites'
```

#### 問題

出力は現在、求めたいものが取得できていません。
出力

```
T-shirt
```

そもそも、以下のことは文字列処理だけで可能なのでしょうか.
自然言語処理のライブラリなどが必要ですか。

- `T-shirt`は出力して
- `peach`は`-peach`はハイフンを削除して一致とするのに
- `T`や`shirt`は意味的には`T-shirt`の一部だから抽出しない

ハイフンの扱いが難しい場合、以下の記号だけでもなんとかしたいです。

```
orange/apple:grape　[fruites]
```

#### コード

コードは別サイト「[スペースやハイフンも完全一致の場合だけ文字列を取得したいが１つのコードで処理できない](https://teratail.com/questions/298342)」という質問の回答を参考に一部追記しました。

```py
text = "orange/apple:grape-peach T-shirt [fruites]"
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'peach', 'T-shirt', 'fruite', 'T', 'shirt']

#求めたい出力
#'apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'peach', 'T-shirt', 'fruite'

splitted = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(' .,!:[]/?'), text.split()))
print(splitted)
for word in words:
    if word in splitted:
        print(word)
    elif " " in word:
        try:
            result = [splitted.index(subword) for subword in word.split()]
            for i in range(len(result)):
                if i > 0 and result[i] != result[i - 1] + 1:
                    continue
            print(word)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

#### 開発環境

python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の方法では、ある単語が他の単語にハイフン付で含まれている場合には `text` を検索しない、という処理にしています。

```py
import re
text = "orange/apple:grape-peach T-shirt [fruites]"
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'peach', 'T-shirt', 'fruites', 'T', 'shirt']

matches = [
  w for w in words
  if all([
       not(re.match(fr'.*(-{w}|{w}-).*', u))
       for u in words if u != w
     ])
  and w in text
]
print(matches)

=>
['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'peach', 'T-shirt', 'fruites']
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。`matches = [
  w for w in words
  if all([
       not(re.match(fr'.*(-{w}|{w}-).*', u))
       for u in words if u != w
     ])
  and w in text
]` の部分をリストでそのまま格納ではなく, １単語ずつ改行などで`print(w)`のように表示するにはどうなりますか.内包記法で少しわからないので, 分けて書いていただけると助かります。

Comment: `print(', '.join(matches))` とします(カンマ区切り)。